# Hibernate JPA maven

Tags: hibernate, jpa, glassfish

I want to use Hibernate as JPA provider with glassfish server.
I added hiberante-entitymanager dependency with maven but i keep getting this error every time i run the project. Am i missing another dependency.

> SEVERE: Exception while deploying the app [JobManager-ear] SEVERE:
>   Invalid ejb jar [JobManager-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar]: it contains zero
>   ejb.  Note: 
>   1. A valid ejb jar requires at least one session, entity (1.x/2.x style), or message-driven bean. 
>   2. EJB3+ entity beans (@Entity) are POJOs and please package them as library jar. 
>   3. If the jar file contains valid EJBs which are annotated with EJB component level annotations (@Stateless, @Stateful, @MessageDriven,
>   @Singleton), please check server.log to see whether the annotations
>   were processed properly. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid
>   ejb jar [JobManager-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar]: it contains zero ejb. 
>   Note: 
>   1. A valid ejb jar requires at least one session, entity (1.x/2.x style), or message-driven bean. 
>   2. EJB3+ entity beans (@Entity) are POJOs and please package them as library jar. 
>   3. If the jar file contains valid EJBs which are annotated with EJB component level annotations (@Stateless, @Stateful, @MessageDriven,
>   @Singleton), please check server.log to see whether the annotations
>   were processed properly.  at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.EjbBundleValidator.accept(EjbBundleValidator.java:76)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.ApplicationValidator.accept(ApplicationValidator.java:128)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.EjbBundleDescriptor.visit(EjbBundleDescriptor.java:730)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.Application.visit(Application.java:1765)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.validate(ApplicationArchivist.java:830)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.openWith(ApplicationArchivist.java:277)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openWith(ApplicationFactory.java:240)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:175)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:94)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:827)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:769)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:368)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

this is pom.xml content:

> ```
> <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>         <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
>         <version>4.1.10.Final</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>antlr</groupId>
>         <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
>         <version>2.7.7</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
>         <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
>         <version>1.6.1</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
>         <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
>         <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>         <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
>         <version>4.1.10.Final</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
>         <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
>         <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
>         <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
>         <version>3.15.0-GA</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
>         <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
>         <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>javax</groupId>
>         <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
>         <version>6.0</version>
>         <scope>provided</scope>
>     </dependency>
> </dependencies>
> ```

help please.

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Use above Maven Repository for JPA.